# How can ı get the Device İnformation on my Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart

hi guys i want to show my device model inside my flutter app. I used device_info_plus package but it didn't work. How can I do that?

Comment: How come "it didn't work" ? What was the error ?

Comment: It's impossible for to help you as you didn't specify what you did, what your code is, what you're expecting (or trying to achieve) and what you actually got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Into your **pubspec.yaml** add the **device_info** package:

```
    dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter
      device_info: ^2.0.3
```

in your dart code just add this and will see device information:

```
  import 'package:device_info/device_info.dart';


  showInfoDevice(){
    String deviceInfo;
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
        IosDeviceInfo iosInfo =
            await DeviceInfoPlugin().iosInfo;
        deviceInfo = iosInfo.utsname.machine;
    } else {
      AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo =
          await DeviceInfoPlugin()
               .androidInfo;
      deviceInfo = androidInfo.model;
    }
    print(deviceInfo);
 }
 
 void initState(){
      super.initState();
      showInfoDevice();
 }
```

Comment: `showInfoDevice() async {
    String deviceInfo;
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
        IosDeviceInfo iosInfo =
            await DeviceInfoPlugin().iosInfo;
        deviceInfo = iosInfo.utsname.machine;
    } else {
      AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo =
          await DeviceInfoPlugin()
               .androidInfo;
      deviceInfo = androidInfo.model;
    }
    print(deviceInfo);
 }`
don't you need async ?

Answer (score 2):

As of now please use this package:

```
dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter
      device_info_plus: ^4.0.1
```

Link: https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus